# what does flush mean in this sentence "flush with the paper"?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/xnarltDAUZQ?t=168)

> the correct depth is you want your drywall screw to be **flush** with the
>   paper

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flush) gives these explanations about flush

> When you flush, you become red in the face, especially as a result of strong emotions, heat, or alcohol:
>
> If you flush a toilet, or if a toilet flushes, its contents empty and it fills with water again:

none of them apply this situation, so, what does flush mean in this sentence "flush with the paper"?

Comment: Look a little further down the page and you will find: “ at the same level as another surface:
*I want the light fittings to be flush with the ceiling.*”

Comment: If you want to explore the origins of the *apparently* unrelated meanings of “flush” go to Etymonline here: https://www.etymonline.com/word/flush?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_8948

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of flush in this sentence is (from your Cambridge Dictionary entry):

> - at the same level as another surface: *I want the light fittings to
>     be flush with the ceiling.*

This meaning of “flush” seems very unlike its other meanings, but all the meanings are thought to be related. To read more about the origins and meanings of “flush” go to ***Etymonline*** [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flush?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_8948).